# How can I add or remove class name in Angular?

Tags: angular

I want to add `desActive` class name when I press the button. And also remove when I press other button.

**Expectation**: when I open site, the `btn1` button has the class `desActive`. If I press the button `btn2`, the `desActive` class is removed from `btn1` and switches to `btn2`.

```
<div class="btn-group description" >
    <button id="btn1" class="desc2 desActive">Description</button>
    <button id="btn2" class="desc3">Reveiwes</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically attach/detach classes you can use `ngClass` (more [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)) or Class-Binding (more [here](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#binding-to-the-class-attribute)).

**`ngClass`**

For both solution you need a variable to store information which button is currently selected.

comp.component.ts

```
// A helper variable to store the currently selected button
selected: number;

selectButton(selectNum: number){
  this.selected = selectNum;
}
```

comp.component.html

```
<div class="btn-group description" >
  <button 
    (click)="selectButton(2)" 
    [ngClass]="{ 'desActive': selected === 2}" 
    class="desc2"
  >
    Description
  </button>

  <button 
    (click)="selectButton(3)" 
    [ngClass]="{ 'desActive': selected === 3}" 
    class="desc3"
  >
    Reviews
  </button>

</div>
```

**Class-Binding**

The Typescript part here would be the same as in the example above, so I don't add it here again.

But the HTML looks a bit different

comp.component.html

```
<div class="btn-group description" >
  <button 
    (click)="selectButton(2)" 
    [class.desActive]="selected === 2" 
    class="desc2"
  >
    Description
  </button>

  <button 
    (click)="selectButton(3)" 
    [class.desActive]="selected === 3" 
    class="desc3"
  >
    Reviews
  </button>

</div>
```

*NOTE: The Typescript part is **just** an example how you could store the selected button in a variable.*

**Update:**

To solve the issue you mentioned in the comment you have two options.

**Option 1:**

Add a `?` to the variable declaration

```
selected?: number;
```

The `?` marks the variable as optional.

**Option 2:**

Initialize the variable in the constructor, e.g., with 2.

```
constructor(){
  this.selected = 2; 
}
```

I would recommend option 1 if you don't want to have a pre-selected button.

Comment: I did your ngClass solition. Its perfectly work. thankyou for solving problem and spend time also good answer...

Comment: If an answer suits you and fixed your problem, please accept the answer, so others know that your question has been answered successfully.

Comment: thanks for info. I wish u go to the heaven :D

Answer (score 0):

<button [ngClass]="isActive ? 'desc2 desActive' : 'desc2'">Description

You can use above code if you are okay.

Comment: I get an error "TS2339: Property 'isActive' does not exist on type 'ContentComponent'."

Comment: maybe I need some click event I guess ?

Comment: You would have to define isActive:boolean in your component. You can then toggle it with button press.

Comment: Thank you I tried and Its hardly work, not exactly the same what I wanted. Anyway thank you for your time.